# How do I get this JS code from Codepen to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the link to codepen: https://codepen.io/rishabhp/pen/aNXVbQ?limit=all&page=7&q=navigation+bar

I am using Brackets and created a html,css,js file. Everything seems to be working except for the js. I've linked the css and js files on the head section. Do I somehow have to link something else or download an extra file?

Head tag looks like this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="theFile.js"></script>
```

HTML code:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#1">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">Second</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">Third</a></li>
    <li><a href="#4">Fourth</a></li>
    <li><a href="#5">Fifth</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="sections">
  <section id="1"><h1>First</h1></section>
  <section id="2"><h1>Second</h1></section>
  <section id="3"><h1>Third</h1></section>
  <section id="4"><h1>Fourth</h1></section>
  <section id="5"><h1>Fifth</h1></section>
</div>

<footer></footer>

<script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

CSS code:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

/* Navigation */

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px; 
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0;
  background: #1ABC9C;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
nav ul li a {
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #34495E;
}
a.active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ecf0f1;
}

/* Headings */

h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: #34495E;
}

/* Sections */

section {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
}
section:nth-child(even) {
  background: #ecf0f1;
}
section:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #bdc3c7;
}
.sections section:first-child {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
section.active {}

footer {
  height: 500px;
  background: #34495e;
}
```

JS code:

```
var sections = $('section')
  , nav = $('nav')
  , nav_height = nav.outerHeight();

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  var cur_pos = $(this).scrollTop();

  sections.each(function() {
    var top = $(this).offset().top - nav_height,
        bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();

    if (cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom) {
      nav.find('a').removeClass('active');
      sections.removeClass('active');

      $(this).addClass('active');
      nav.find('a[href="#'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').addClass('active');
    }
  });
});

nav.find('a').on('click', function () {
  var $el = $(this)
    , id = $el.attr('href');

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(id).offset().top - nav_height
  }, 500);

  return false;
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any console errors in the browser?

Comment: As Phani said, try checking the developer's console by clicking <kbd>F12</kbd> and possibly clicking Esc if it doesn't appear at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include your JavaScript files after including the `jquery.min.js`. Otherwise your code gets executed before jQuery is initialized.

Remove `<script src="theFile.js"></script>` in the `head` tag and add it at the very bottom of your HTML.

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#1">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">Second</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">Third</a></li>
    <li><a href="#4">Fourth</a></li>
    <li><a href="#5">Fifth</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="sections">
  <section id="1"><h1>First</h1></section>
  <section id="2"><h1>Second</h1></section>
  <section id="3"><h1>Third</h1></section>
  <section id="4"><h1>Fourth</h1></section>
  <section id="5"><h1>Fifth</h1></section>
</div>

<footer></footer>

<script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="theFile.js"></script>
```

You can check your console (shortcut: F12), there should be a error like

```
$ is not defined
```

in the console.

---

#### Edit:

You can ensure jQuery is initialized when your code is executed by waiting to load the page completely. You just have to wrap your code with `$(document).ready()` function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sections = $('section')
      , nav = $('nav')
      , nav_height = nav.outerHeight();

    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
      var cur_pos = $(this).scrollTop();

      sections.each(function() {
        var top = $(this).offset().top - nav_height,
            bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();

        if (cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom) {
          nav.find('a').removeClass('active');
          sections.removeClass('active');

          $(this).addClass('active');
          nav.find('a[href="#'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').addClass('active');
        }
      });
    });

    nav.find('a').on('click', function () {
      var $el = $(this)
        , id = $el.attr('href');

      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(id).offset().top - nav_height
      }, 500);

      return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still getting the '$' was used before it was defined.

Comment: Bracket feels that there are 5 errors within the js file, i'll fix them by adding the following: /*jslint browser: true*/
/*global $, jQuery, alert*/

Comment: @ModChelly I updated the answer to use `$(document).ready()` function.

Comment: Seems to be a plugin malfunction I just tried the 1.6.4 jquery and added a red border to all divs and it worked..

Comment: With your original code? If so, may be you should mention it in the question as an edit.

Comment: Just checking a few things first, thank you so very much.

Comment: Added an offline version of the jquery to the folder and did the javascript within the html file. And it worked. Thanks! I'll figure why javascript is not working within its own file tmmrw!